# Apex error message: Internal Server Error when doing callout

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout

I have a program to do external callout for which the process gets invoked by the apex trigger.

1. A workflow to immediately update a field from 0 - 8 if X field was changed to Y value
2. Then the respective trigger and handler execute the appropriate process until the point where the callout is invoked.

Here is the callout method;

```
public class AgentPortalManager{

    public static String createJSONBody(Map<String, String> variables){
       
        /// create the JSON body ///

        return body.getAsString();
    }
    
    @future(callout = true)
    public static void requestAPI(String body, String country, Id ppID){

        String username = 'username';
        String password = 'password';
        String clientId = 'clientid';
        String clientSecret = 'clientsecret';

        Map<String, String> credentialsMap = new Map<String, String>();
        credentialsMap.put('username', username);
        credentialsMap.put('password', password);
        credentialsMap.put('client_id', clientId);
        credentialsMap.put('client_secret', clientSecret);
        credentialsMap.put('grant_type', 'password');

        string credentialsJSON = JSON.serialize(credentialsMap);

        String tokenAPEndpoint;
        String formattedTokenEndpoint;
        String token;
        String lowerCaseCountry;
        String[] formatArguments;
        
        switch on country {
            when 'MyP' {
                tokenAPEndpoint = 'xxx';
                lowerCaseCountry = country.toLowerCase().replace('y', '');
                System.assertEquals('mp', lowerCaseCountry);
            }
            when else {
                tokenAPEndpoint = 'xxx';
                lowerCaseCountry = country.toLowerCase();
            }
        }

        try {

            formatArguments = new String[]{lowerCaseCountry};
            formattedTokenEndpoint = String.format(tokenAPEndpoint, formatArguments);
            System.debug('URL Token Endpoint' + formattedTokenEndpoint);

            HttpRequest requestToken = new HttpRequest();
            requestToken.setEndpoint(formattedTokenEndpoint);
            requestToken.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            requestToken.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
            requestToken.setBody(credentialsJSON);  
            requestToken.setMethod('POST');
           
            Integer i = 1;
            Map<String, Object> mapGetRequest = new Map<String, Object>();

            while (i <= 5) {

                Http httpGetToken = new Http();
                HttpResponse responseToken = httpGetToken.send(requestToken);

                system.debug('Response Token' + responseToken);
                system.debug('notification this get_token' + responseToken.getBody());
    
                mapGetRequest = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseToken.getBody());

                if(responseToken.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    break;
                }

                system.debug('iteration #' + i);
                i++;
            }

            token = 'Bearer ' + mapGetRequest.get('access_token');
            system.debug('access token ' + mapGetRequest.get('access_token'));

            // ******************* end of token request part ******************* //

            String messageEndpoint = 'xxx';
            String formattedMessageEndpoint;
            formattedMessageEndpoint = String.format(messageEndpoint, formatArguments); 

            System.debug('URL Message Endpoint ' + formattedMessageEndpoint);

            HttpRequest requestMessage = new HttpRequest();
            requestMessage.setEndpoint(formattedMessageEndpoint);
            requestMessage.setHeader('Accept' ,'application/json');
            requestMessage.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            requestMessage.setHeader('authorization','Bearer ' + token);
            requestMessage.setMethod('POST');
            requestMessage.setBody(body);

            System.debug('body of JSON ' + body);
            System.debug('bearer token  ' + token);
            
            Http httpRequestMessage = new Http();
            HttpResponse responseMessage = httpRequestMessage.send(requestMessage);

            if(responseMessage.getStatusCode() == 201){
            
                system.debug('Response Push to AP ' + responseMessage);
                system.debug('notification this Push to AP ' + responseMessage.getBody());
                
                Map<String, Object> mapPostRequest = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseMessage.getBody());
                system.debug('conversation Id ' + mapPostRequest.get('id'));

                String angiConversationID = String.valueOf(mapPostRequest.get('id'));

                List<TDeal__c> updatePP = [SELECT Id, InsertedtoAP__c, AngiLeadID__c FROM TDeal__c WHERE Id =: ppID Limit 1];
                System.debug('Size of updatePP: ' + updatePP.size());
                
                if(updatePP.size() > 0) {
                    updatePP[0].InsertedtoAP__c = true;
                    updatePP[0].AngiLeadID__c = angiConversationID;
                    updatePP[0].TriggerMessageAP__c = 0;
                update updatePP[0];
                }
            }else if (responseMessage.getStatus()=='Bad Request' || responseMessage.getStatusCode() == 400) {
                sendErrroMail('Bad Request Error', body);
            }else if (responseMessage.getStatus()=='Internal Server Error' || responseMessage.getStatusCode() == 500) {
                sendErrroMail('Internal Server Error', body);
            }else if (responseMessage.getStatus()=='Unauthorised' || responseMessage.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                sendErrroMail('Unauthorised Error', body);
            }
            
        } catch (CalloutException excpObj) {
            System.debug(' Callout Exception ---- ERROR = ' + excpObj.getMessage());
            sendErrroMail(excpObj.getMessage(), body);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('An exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            sendErrroMail(e.getMessage(), body);              
            
        }
        
    }
```

This program works fine but sometimes I encounter an "Internal Server Error" at the `httpRequestMessage`  and I'm not sure whether it's from my script or from the target endpoint that caused the problem.

Any help and advices to make my script more efficient and meet best practices would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Which API call re you getting error for? is it while you are getting the `httpGetToken` or for `httpRequestMessage`?

Comment: ```httpRequestMessage``` for this one, I edited my question.

Comment: it definitely is from an external system. Do you have their API documentation where you can compare the API request? that should get you a better idea or even a log from the API maybe?

Comment: ah so it's from the external, I'll try to deep dive into their docs then. thanks!